# syntax error: unexpected end of the file

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
#organization: Seneca College
#Purpose: Validate a date
#Usage: chkdate year month day
#

year=$1; month=$2; day=$3; extra=$4
if [[ "$year" == "" || "$month" == "" || "$day" == "" ]]; then
        # Not enough data!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 0
fi
if [[ ! ( $year =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $month =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $day =~ ^[0-9]+$ ) ]]; then
        # Date not numeric!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 1
fi
if [[ $year -lt 1 || $year -gt 9999 || $month -lt 1 || $month -gt 12 || $day -lt 1 || $day -gt 31 ]]; then
        # Date out of range!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 2
fi
if [[ ( $month == 1 || $month == 3 || $month == 5 || $month == 7 || $month == 8 || $month == 10 || $month == 12 ) && $day -gt 31 ]]; then
        # Invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 3
fi
if [[ ( $month == 4 || $month == 6 || $month == 9 || $month == 11 ) && $day -gt 30 ]]; then
        # Invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 4
fi
if [[ ($month == 9) && ($year == 1752) && ( $day -gt 2) && $day -le 14  ]] ; then
        #invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 5

date -d $2/$3/$1 > /dev/null 2>&1
if [[ "$@" ]] ; then
        echo "valid date"
else
        echo "not a valid"
fi
```

it says my script has line 44 however my script total lines are 43

Comment: You've been downvoted because Google is your friend.  See [Case 4](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/), and add Ramesh's answer. Your script does have 44 lines.  Kate confirms it.  Delete the extra carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

You have an unterminated `if` loop. Add a `fi` for this `if` loop.

```
if [[ ($month == 9) && ($year == 1752) && ( $day -gt 2) && $day -le 14  ]]
```

After adding an `fi`, when I run your script, this is what I get as output.

```
chkdate 1342 1 21
valid date
chkdate 13as 1 21
Usage: chkdate year month day
```

Comment: ye i missed a fi i fixed it thou thx for rply

Comment: @HajirGolmohammadi If it solved your issue, please mark this answer as accepted.